# Nexus 3 Docker repo - bad gateway

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-registry

I created a Docker Repo on Nexus 3. The URL looks like this:

```
https://myserver.net/nexus3/repository/docker-images/
```

I enabled `Create an HTTP connector at specified port` for port *8123*.
I configured my Docker daemon to allow "insecure registry" `myserver.net:8123`.

I am behind a proxy and entered this proxy in Docker settings. But this proxy is NOT used for myserver.net, so I added myserver.net to "Bypass for these hosts and domains".

When I now do `docker login myserver.net:8123` I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

Any ideas?

Edit:

A Screenshot of my Nexus settings:
[image]

Comment: That url looks like a path based reverse proxy. The docker registry needs to be at the root of the url, not under a path. The normal way to do that is expose a different port for the docker registry.

Comment: @BMitch I thought that's why "Create an HTTP connector at specified port" is used for?!

Comment: Did you include the port number in your no_proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

Add `NO_PROXY` environment variable to your [docker deamon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy).